# How do you "echo" quotes using python's os.system()?

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7

I'm trying to write to a monit config file using standard bash scripting inside if python's `os.system()`, this string is what I'd like to mimic.

```
echo -e "\t" start program = \""/etc/init.d/snortd00 start\"" >> /etc/monit.d/ips_svcs.monit
```

Here are my attempts using `os.system()`. They all produce the same results. None of which are writing the quotes around `/etc/init.d/snortd00 start`

```
   os.system('echo -e \"\t\" start program = \""/etc/init.d/snortd00 start\"" >> /etc/monit.d/ips_svcs.monit')

   os.system('echo -e \"\t\" start program = \"\"/etc/init.d/snortd00 start\"\" >> /etc/monit.d/ips_svcs.monit')

   os.system('echo -e \"\t\" start program = "/etc/init.d/snortd00 start" >> /etc/monit.d/ips_svcs.monit')

   os.system('echo -e \"\t\" start program = "\"/etc/init.d/snortd00 start\"" >> /etc/monit.d/ips_svcs.monit')
```

This is what is being written using all four `os.system()` statments. `start program = /etc/init.d/snortd00 start`

I'm looking for this `start program = "/etc/init.d/snortd00 start"`

Comment: Fun fact: you can [append a line to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file-in-python) using only Python, no bash code required.

Comment: Can you please provide the expected result? This will make the problem way easier to solve...

Comment: @juhist, that worked. Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's consider why your existing approaches are not working:

In this case, the `\` is processed by Python, so the shell gets two consecutive " characters. The shell sees `""/etc...""`:

```
os.system('echo -e \"\t\" start program = \""/etc/init.d/snortd00 start\"" >> /etc/monit.d/ips_svcs.monit')
```

This is the same as previous: the `\` is processed by Python:

```
os.system('echo -e \"\t\" start program = \"\"/etc/init.d/snortd00 start\"\" >> /etc/monit.d/ips_svcs.monit')
```

In this case, the shell sees "/etc...":

```
os.system('echo -e \"\t\" start program = "/etc/init.d/snortd00 start" >> /etc/monit.d/ips_svcs.monit')
```

In this case also, Python processes `\` and the shell sees `""/etc...""`:

```
os.system('echo -e \"\t\" start program = "\"/etc/init.d/snortd00 start\"" >> /etc/monit.d/ips_svcs.monit')
```

Now, what you want:

```
os.system('echo -e \"\t\" start program = \\"/etc/init.d/snortd00 start\\" >> /etc/monit.d/ips_svcs.monit')
```

Here, Python processes `\\` into `\` and the Shell sees `\"`, which invokes the escaping mechanism of the shell so `echo` really sees `"`.

Answer (score 8):

Just use a raw string to avoid double-escaping (once for python, once for the shell):

```
cmd = r'echo -e "\t" start program = \""/etc/init.d/snortd00 start\"" >> /etc/monit.d/ips_svcs.monit'
os.system(cmd)
```

As tripleee points out in the comments, [`os.system` is being replaced by subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), so the code above would change to this:

```
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Better yet, just use python:

```
with open("/etc/monit.d/ips_svcs.monit", "a") as file:
    file.write('\t  start program = "/etc/init.d/snortd00 start"\n')
```

Comment: +1 for the proper Python code suggestion... Although, there should probably be a newline in the `write()` call, since it's not added automatically like `print ...` would...

Comment: Perhaps also tangentially note that `os.system()` is [being replaced by `subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) although the [recommended replacement code](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system) is rather unattractive. But maybe that's just to encourage you to use Python's own facilities when that makes sense.